# tensorflow make_template in PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, torch

I am transferring something from tensorflow to PyTorch. In tensorflow code the [make_template](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/make_template) method was used. I am wondering what is the synonym for that in PyTorch.

Code example:

> self.var = tf.make_template('var_name', SomeClass(param1, param2))

Thank you!

Comment: What does the template do with the object of `SomeClass`? Variable sharing in general, does not involve anything special in PyTorch, you just use the variable in different places, like you would in regular Python.

Comment: @MichaelJungo These templates are used in `__call__` afterwards.

Comment: So, it basically imitates [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module) where the shared variable are assigned to an attribute and then used for multiple (forward) calls or multiple times within the same call?

Comment: @MichaelJungo in tensorflow code (Keras) it is like        `output_1 = self.var_1(images)
        output_2 = self.var_2(masks)
        return output_1, output_2`  ; `var_1` and `var_2` here are instances of `SomeClass`

Comment: @MichaelJungo But I guess, you are right, `nn.Module` is what I need, code example here: https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/deep_residual_network/main.py